# "Ask for Finder Items" in Swift

Tags: swift, finder, nsworkspace

I am trying to open a file-browsing window similar to the one shown in the screenshot where you can "select files and click open/select" in my Swift application when the user clicks on the "Browse" button.

[image: temporary Finder window]

In Automator, this is done by using the "Ask for Finder Items" action, and in Swift

```
NSWorkspace().selectFile("\(fileName)", inFileViewerRootedAtPath: "/Library")
```

opens up a new instance of Finder.app itself; what should I do if I would like to emulate the behavior seen in the Automator action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/) class. It has several configurable properties for which kinds of files can be selected, and when the user finishes selecting files, you can access them via the `URLs` property. You can also read more about it in the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels.html).